# Weird behaviour on solr while using a custom indexing plugin on multivalued field

Tags: plugins, solr, behavior, multivalue

I'm using my custom plugin to index a bunch of xml in solr.
What this plugin does is "tag" documents and add those tags (comma separated) in a multivalued field.

This is what i have inside my log:

```
...
[MULTIVALUE CAR TYPE - final result] -> 4 Dr. Wagon with Wagon, 4X4,
...
```

This is what i actually have inside the solr instance when faceting:

```
<lst name="car_type_multivalue">
    <int name="convertible">331</int>
    <int name="4">152</int>
    <int name="x">152</int>
    <int name="wagon">121</int>
```

This is how the field is defined:

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
     <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
     </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

As you can see 4x4 is added correctly to the tags of a document, but when it's faceted it's actually split between "4" and "x". My field type doesn't seem to allow something like this, so the question is why is solr behaving like this? All the other values work correctly, but not "4x4". Can i presume that everytime i find an "x" in my tags, it's going to be split no matter what? Thanks all!

Comment: sorry, i actually got this, didn't see it before because. i have that worddelimiter filter factory screwing things up. sorry for the post.